# How do I change background image on stars?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a css hover effect.
I want the previous stars to also change their background image as the stars are hovered.

I have tried some different things but can't seem to understand the `CSS` that has to be used. Can anybody guide me?

I have the rating project [here](http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/rating/index.php)

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="absolute babesRate flex">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" id="vote1">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="vote" value="2" id="vote2">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="vote" value="3" id="vote3">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="vote" value="4" id="vote4">
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="vote" value="5" id="vote5">
    </label>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
label{
    background-image: url(../img/voteEmpty.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
label+input[type="radio"]:checked{
    background-image: url(../img/voteFull.png);
}
label:hover{
    background-image: url(../img/voteFull.png);
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples of this. https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/vlpkh and http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/star-rating-widget/ are good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like this, where you put the `input` outside the `label`, or else they will not "see" the label(s), and then, with the flexbox `order` property, you swap them in markup so you can make use of the sibling selector `~`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray url(../img/voteEmpty.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}
label:nth-of-type(1) { order: 5; }
label:nth-of-type(2) { order: 4; }
label:nth-of-type(3) { order: 3; }
label:nth-of-type(4) { order: 2; }
label:nth-of-type(5) { order: 1; }

input:checked ~ label {
  background: red url(../img/voteFull.png);
}
form:hover label {
  background: gray url(../img/voteEmpty.png); 
}
form label:hover,
label:hover ~ label {
  background: red url(../img/voteFull.png);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="absolute babesRate flex">
  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="5" id="vote5">
  <label for="vote5">5</label>
  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="4" id="vote4">
  <label for="vote4">4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="3" id="vote3">
  <label for="vote3">3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="2" id="vote2">
  <label for="vote2">2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" id="vote1">
  <label for="vote1">1</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I ended giving you thumbs up because you were closest, i ended up using this css class .flex-drr{flex-direction:row-reverse;}

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your styles, you have this:

```
.parent label:hover,
.parent label:hover ~ label {
   background-image: url(../img/voteFull.png);
}
```

Change that to this one:

```
label:hover,
label:hover ~ label {
   background-image: url(../img/voteFull.png);
}
```

Comment: I know its achieveable with CSS, i just cant get it to work.. If you check the link http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/rating/index.php you can see it is actually working not, except it is mirroring the way it really should be

Comment: No the script has nothing to do with the hover, it is my code :) I can remove the script if you want to it still works... look the css, also here is a tut where it is done with css, i just cant figure out how to do it with my project https://www.everythingfrontend.com/posts/star-rating-input-pure-css.html